# How do I make my own terminal command with flags?

Tags: high-sierra

So suppose I want to make a terminal command and I also want to add specific flags how do I accomplish this? What is the syntax for this and how do accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @Dancingmachine, well done is your title. For receiving answers it helps when your question is more concrete in telling what you are trying to achieve. For instance give an example. It also helps when you tell what you did already try (even if that didn't work out). Please edit and improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is probably off-topic I want to provide an answer: to start with simple bash scripting get in touch with `getopts`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "I'm the $OPTARG coder in the world." >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Save this bash script as `coder` in a directory in the PATH and make it executable with `chmod +x coder`. If you choose another name don't replace an already existing file with the same name! Choose a unique name! The bash script checks for the flag/option -a and takes the argument after the flag to echo a sentence. The script doesn't check if the result is grammatically correct!

Examples:

`coder -a best` will result in `I'm the best coder in the world`.
`coder -a "most yellow"` will result in `I'm the most yellow coder in the world`.

but:

`coder -a most yellow` will result in `I'm the most coder in the world`.

or

`coder -b "most yellow"` > `Invalid option: -b`.